# dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Address already in use

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I'm trying to set up `dnsmasq` on `AWS Ubuntu 20.4`  by following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq) link.

However, I can't seem to get around the error `dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use`

I've tried the steps in these posts with no success:

1. [dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191226/dnsmasq-failed-to-create-listening-socket-for-port-53-address-already-in-use)
2. https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/dnsmasq-failed-to-create-listening-socket-for-port-53-permission-denied/16436
3. https://jonamiki.com/2020/01/29/dnsmasq-failed-to-create-listening-socket-for-port-53-address-already-in-use/
4. [dnsmasq : failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062651/dnsmasq-failed-to-create-listening-socket-for-port-53-address-already-in-use)

The only thing that has had any obvious impact has been `sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service` which changed the error message from `dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use` to `dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Address already in use`

I'm not sure what's actually running on 53 because, if I run `sudo ss -alpn sport = 53 src 127.0.0.1` there is no output, nothing is apparently listening on port 53. However, If I run `sudo ss -lp "sport = :domain"` my output is:

```
Netid       State        Recv-Q       Send-Q             Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port      Process                                  
udp         UNCONN       0            0                        0.0.0.0:domain                  0.0.0.0:*          users:(("dnsmasq",pid=2059,fd=4))       
udp         UNCONN       0            0                           [::]:domain                     [::]:*          users:(("dnsmasq",pid=2059,fd=6))       
tcp         LISTEN       0            32                       0.0.0.0:domain                  0.0.0.0:*          users:(("dnsmasq",pid=2059,fd=5))       
tcp         LISTEN       0            32                          [::]:domain                     [::]:*          users:(("dnsmasq",pid=2059,fd=7))
```

My `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` looks like:

```
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8#53
listen-address=127.0.0.1
cache-size=50
```

I tried enabling `bind-interfaces` in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` which made no difference.

And I also tried to make sure to stop systemd-resolved service and I masked it so auto start on reboot.

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl mask systemd-resolved
```

Again, no difference.

Checking `sudo systemctl dnsmasq.service` returns:

```
Unknown operation dnsmasq.service.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-27-116:~$ sudo systemctl status dnsmasq.service
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-02-13 19:55:05 UTC; 36s ago
    Process: 3381 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --test (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3382 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-exec (code=exited, status=2)

Feb 13 19:55:04 ip-172-31-27-116 systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Feb 13 19:55:05 ip-172-31-27-116 dnsmasq[3381]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Feb 13 19:55:05 ip-172-31-27-116 dnsmasq[3382]: dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Address already in use
Feb 13 19:55:05 ip-172-31-27-116 dnsmasq[3382]: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Address already in use
Feb 13 19:55:05 ip-172-31-27-116 dnsmasq[3382]: FAILED to start up
Feb 13 19:55:05 ip-172-31-27-116 systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Feb 13 19:55:05 ip-172-31-27-116 systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 13 19:55:05 ip-172-31-27-116 systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
```

Comment: the --bind-dynamic flag gets me beyond the error. I am not making the effort to actually set it up or test it... So I don't know any further results. `dnsmasq -d  --bind-dynamic -a 127.10.0.1` on the command line, got the service start and listen on the port... without the flag, I get the same error.

Comment: `dnsmasq: cannot set --bind-interfaces and --bind-dynamic` is all I get.